# Changing text color on output

Tags: colors

I have written a text based game for the class I am taking, but I want to see how I can change certain output text to different colors. Say the villain loses, the text prints out red or something, and vice versa, if he wins, the text prints out in like blue. Do I need to define all the colors first, or is there a way to add it to the string? example:

```
print('Thank you for playing but unfortunately you lost your life!')
```

How can I change the output to red text?

Answer (score 0):

is this python?
If so here is a link to a few options [python colors](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-colors-python-terminal/)

in your case I guess you want to have something like:

```
text = colored('Thank you for playing but unfortunately you lost your life!', 'red', attrs=['reverse', 'blink'])
print(text)
```

Comment: Yes sorry in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I'm basing my game off Game of Thrones. Here a sample of the output when the character loses. I'm still working on the story.

```
        else:
            print('\nOh dear! You did not collect all of the items!')
            print('You were caught by Daenerys and set on fire by Drogon!')
            print('Drogon escaped and set the township on fire!')
            print('Thank you for playing but unfortunately you lost your life!')
            print('You must start over')
```